# Has anyone tried to do a preauth for x amount?

Tags: magento2, payment, partial-payments

I have an issue where a client wants to do an initial authorization of $1.00 before the actual amount gets authorized.

So, we have an order total of $50, I want to change the payment amount to $1.00, have that get authorized first. If that is successful, then we authorize the full amount.

I've tried changing the payment sent, the order totals..etc and nothing is working. When I changed the payment sent to the gateway, I kept getting fraudulent errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct post didn't really work for me, so I used a CIM extension that did a pre-auth and that worked

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to checkout Authorize.net CIM, or any payment service that provides a mechanism for storing customer card data for repeated billing. In my experience, authorizations can be captured once and only up to the original amount authorized.

Comment: It's not really repeat billing. It's like what gas stations do and charge an initial $1 to make sure the card is active before charging the full amount, then they void the initial transaction

Comment: That's a card present transaction, which is very different from what you are wanting to do in the eyes of a processor. Ultimately you'll need to talk it over with your payment provider.

Comment: Creating a transaction, voiding it, and creating another isn't unheard of and I've already done it on another e-commerce platform it just doesn't work on magento. If you haven't tried it, that's fine. Was hoping somebody in the Magneto world had tried this